# Install standalone WPF application and integrate with add/remove programs using Windows Setup Project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project

I have a Windows Setup project that installs 2 windows services, copies over a bunch of executables and driver files, and then installs a driver. I want to add a WPF project to my solution, and then deploy it with the same behavior as ClickOnce -- I want an entry in the Add/Remove Programs list, with an option to Uninstall. I know that I won't be able to update this program without updating and redeploying the MSI, unlike ClickOnce which has automatic updates.

I have tried adding the project output to the custom actions, file system, programs folder, and desktop. This only copies the final .exe for my wpf application to these areas, but it does not register the application as part of the system apps.

The actual setup project has a row created in Add/Remove Programs, so I can uninstall all my services and remove the copied files from the system, but I also want another row in Add/Remove Programs for the WPF application.

Please let me know if there is a way to install the WPF application as part of my windows setup installer, and also a way to uninstall if the setup project is being uninstalled or rolled back.

Thanks,

Misha